# What are the requirements for a 'complex' airplane?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, far-61

Requirements for 'complex' airplane seem to vary between regulators and between pilots, so let's have this settled once and for all.

What is the definition of a 'complex' airplane as defined by FAA and EASA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the FAA, a "complex aeroplane" must have:

- A retractable gear (not necessary for a seaplane);
- In-flight adjustable flaps; and
- A controllable pitch propeller.

The FAA's definition is given in [14 CFR 61.1](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=257acc4699ee7253af775fc7e9492e51&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#14:2.0.1.1.2.1.1.1):

> *Complex airplane* means an airplane that has a retractable landing
>   gear, flaps, and a controllable pitch propeller, including airplanes
>   equipped with an engine control system consisting of a digital
>   computer and associated accessories for controlling the engine and
>   propeller, such as a full authority digital engine control; or, in the
>   case of a seaplane, flaps and a controllable pitch propeller,
>   including seaplanes equipped with an engine control system consisting
>   of a digital computer and associated accessories for controlling the
>   engine and propeller, such as a full authority digital engine control.

However, the EASA has a different definition of a "complex motor-powered aircraft" that is an airplane, which is considerably more "complex":

> an aeroplane:
>
> - with a maximum certificated take-off mass exceeding 5 700 kg, or
> - certificated for a maximum passenger seating configuration of more than nineteen, or
> - certificated for operation with a minimum crew of at least two pilots, or
> - equipped with (a) turbojet engine(s) or more than one turboprop engine

Note that 5700kg is about 12567 pounds.

Comment: Could you add the EASA definition aswell, europeans have a pretty different ideea what a complex is : http://www.caa.co.uk/default.aspx?catid=1799&pagetype=90&pageid=10741