# Is it legal to begin pilot training on a jet?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

Disregarding financial and difficulty concerns, would it be possible (legal) for someone to obtain a PPL license on a jet aircraft?

If it is possible, would there be any restrictions on the license on operating piston engine aircrafts?

---

*EDIT: the linked question asks about EASA regulations. This question is about FAA regulations, thus, the answer in the linked question does not apply.*

Comment: Turbines are a separate class, so yes, you would not be allowed to fly piston engines. You'd need to get an extra class rating for that. I don't think there are any restrictions on doing your training using turbines, except your wallet.

Comment: See also [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/are-you-allowed-to-do-your-entire-ppl-on-a-medium-sized-jet-aircraft-from-day-on)

Comment: The linked question basically asks the same thing, only regarding EASA instead of FAA. If someone would kindly amend the answer there, I would close this question.

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8318/62)

Comment: @falstro The FAA doesn't have a separate class for turbine vs. piston. The turbine requires a type rating, but it would all be Airplane - Multi Engine. Couldn't fly single-engine, but piston twin would be OK.

Comment: @NathanG it could be ASEL if its something like an L-39

Comment: @rbp Fair enough, sometimes I forget about single-engine jets. If you could accomplish the checkride in one of those, you'd have an ASEL that works with pistons too.

Comment: The answer is yes; and yes, restricted to same category and class.

Comment: How does one get a solo endorsement for a type rating?

Comment: Here it is in 61.31 (2) Have received training required by this part that is appropriate to the pilot certification level, aircraft category, class, and type rating (if a class or type rating is required) for the aircraft to be flown, and have received an endorsement for solo flight in that aircraft from an authorized instructor.

Comment: This is not duplicate! This is about FAA, the other about EASA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, it is perfectly legal to do your primary training in a jet.

It is becoming common in militaries to do initial training in turboprops.

http://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/t6b/

Managing such a turboprop aircraft is actually simpler than managing your typical piston aircraft. One button start. One lever engine control.

Maybe some day that will become a single engine jet.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing in the US regulations and no references that I can find that prohibits a pilot from learning to fly in a jet aircraft.  There are multiple systems on a jet aircraft that are not found in small GA aircraft and the same systems are more complex.  A lot of professional pilots who fly the same jet for a career don't fully understand the different systems on their jet.

The issue isn't with the FAA though; it is with the instructor and insurance companies.

I certainly would not agree, as a CFII, to train a new student pilot in a jet.  I personally don't want to take on the liability for the payment I would receive for my services.

Most insurance companies will not ensure a student pilot to learn to fly in a jet.