# Are jets deliberately excluded from the "Complex airplane" definition?

Tags: regulations

A jet aircraft seems for sure very complex as such. But, referring Wikipedia, a "complex aircraft" (as legally defined) has:

- A retractable landing gear
- Flaps
- and ***A controllable pitch propeller***

And there is no propeller in a jet.

What are the reasons of defining "complex aircraft" so that it does not cover jets? Are these reasons other than historical?

Comment: What jurisdiction/CAA is this? (FAA, UK CAA, EASA, etc...?)

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1258/62)

Comment: Well, the complexity associated with variable pitch propeller is not there in a jet either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All jets require a type rating. Therefore you don't need the complex endorsement directly (other than needing it likely for your commercial checkride, which requires a complex aircraft). The historical training progression is: simple prop, complex single engine prop (requiring the complex endorsement), high performance (200 hp+, though this one is sometimes not gotten), light multi-engine props, and then finally moving into heavier turboprops and then jets which require type ratings.

Note, my answer is FAA specific, and other agencies might have different rules/interpretations for this issue.

Comment: A small point, but you can get a type rating without getting your commercial license, so you don't necessarily need to have your complex endorsement in order to fly a jet.